# Como fazer o scroll iniciar no fim da pagina?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, laravel

Olá, tenho que fazer um site que começa de baixo para cima, mas não consigo fazer o scroll iniciar no fim da pagina.

esse ai é a script que estou usando:

```
$(function scroll() {
    // scroll all the way down
    $('html').scrollTop($(document).height() - $(window).height()); 
})
```

O problema é que o scroll começa uns 600px acima do fim da página, isso começou depois que fiz a integração dele ao laravel

Comment: Mas com o código que postou a página já é renderizada no fim dela. Para vc testar é só colocar no css um height de 1500px por exemplo no html, que vai ver!

Comment: então eu coloquei a largura total da pagina que da, 5615px só que ele fica uns 600px acima no bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) para realizar a rolagem da altura inteira do `body`.

Sintaxe: `window.scrollTo(eixoX, eixoY)`

```
$(function scroll() {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
})
```

O [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight), segundo o MDN:

> O valor do scrollHeight é igual à altura mínima que o elemento
>   exigiria para caber em todo o conteúdo na viewport sem usar uma barra
>   de rolagem vertical.

Comment: vlw cara deu certo